# Marker cluster how to add jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, markerclusterer

I've inherited a plugin that uses

https://github.com/marioestrada/jQuery-gMap

The way that it produces the markers is like so:

```
var results = [];
    if( locationSet && !jQuery( "li.FYN_viewmap" ).first().hasClass('no-results-found') ){

    jQuery( "li.FYN_viewmap" ).each(function( index ) {

    var distance = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('data-distance')),
    html = '<a href="'+jQuery(this).attr('data-link') + '"><strong>'+jQuery(this).attr('data-title') + '</strong><br /><span style="font-size:0.9em;">' + jQuery(this).attr('data-address') + '</span></a>';        

                                results.push({latitude: jQuery(this).attr('data-lat'), longitude: jQuery(this).attr('data-lng'), html: html});
jQuery('#FYN_map').gMap({
        zoom: zoom,
        markers: results,
        controls:  controls,
        icon: icon,
        });
```

I can't work out how to add google maps clusterer to this. Any ideas?

All of the info I've looked up has this example:

```
var markers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    var latlng = new GLatLng(data.photos[i].latitude, data.photos[i].longitude);
    var marker = new GMarker(latlng);
    markers.push(marker);
  }
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

I can't see how this relates in any way to the code I have in this plugin bearing in mind it has already set the latlng in the var results.

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code `fiddle.jshell.net/:62 Uncaught ReferenceError: locationSet is not defined`.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, including some sample data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking a look at this. I know my code was a bit vague, but I've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help anyone, but I've found a solution. I'm now using a different googlemaps plugin that has the clusters functionality enabled.

[gmap3](http://gmap3.net/)

To retrieve the array of lat long coordinates I needed to make this change to var results.
`results.push({position: [ jQuery(this).attr('data-lat'), jQuery(this).attr('data-lng') ] });`

And then this displays my map:

```
$('#FYN_map').gmap3({
    center: [56.110182, -4.000124],
    zoom: zoom
  })
  .cluster({
     size: 200,
     markers: results,
      cb: function (markers) {
        if (markers.length > 1) { // 1 marker stay unchanged (because cb returns nothing)
          if (markers.length < 20) {
            return {
              content: "<div class='cluster cluster-1'>" + markers.length + "</div>",
              x: -26,
              y: -26
            };
          }
          if (markers.length < 50) {
            return {
              content: "<div class='cluster cluster-2'>" + markers.length + "</div>",
              x: -26,
              y: -26
            };
          }
          return {
            content: "<div class='cluster cluster-3'>" + markers.length + "</div>",
            x: -33,
            y: -33
          };
        }
      }
  })
;
```

Comment: Ok, this wasn't the correct answer because gmap3 doesn't let you add an infowindow to markers if you have the clusters enabled. Throwing laptop out of window